# Content loaded with jQuery .load() doesn't function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having some porblems with getting JQuery to load an html page. I use JQuery to load this page vvv

```
<a class="codaw" href="#"><img id="codawx_img" src="img/codawx.png" alt="Call of Duty:Advanced Warfare" style="height:150px;"></a>

<script>
$('a.codaw').on('click', function(e){
e.preventDefault();
$('#container').remove();
$('#content').load('second.html'+'#content').hide().fadeIn('slow');
});
</script>
```

and that page loads fine but that ^^^ jquery function wont load the second html content it just loads the href.

I don't know what i am doing wrong here if some one could please share some knowledge i would be thankful.

Comment: What exactly do you mean, "it just loads the href"?

Comment: It loads the href of that link. Like the prevent default() using working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need event delegation. Try this:

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', 'a.codaw', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#container').remove();
        $('#content').load('second.html'+'#content').hide().fadeIn('slow');
    });
});
</script>
```

Reference:

http://davidwalsh.name/event-delegate